# Optical Flow in Matlab

Tags: matlab, opticalflow

How do you compute and display the optical flow of two images in Matlab?
Is their a built in function for this and if so, how do you implement this?

Comment: Have you tried: http://bit.ly/1o89ObT

Comment: Yes I did Google it, however, I could not find any kind of function that does that kind of thing. I am new to using Matlab so if anyone who is familiar with using Matlab could help me I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @enishiyama It would help to actually read the google results. Literally the first result http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.opticalflow-class.html

Comment: I looked at that link. The part that refers to what I am trying to do is: "opticalFlow = vision.OpticalFlow(Name,Value) returns an optical flow System object, H, with each specified property set to the specified value. You can specify additional name-value pair arguments in any order as (Name1, Value1,...,NameN,ValueN)." Do you know what the name has to be? I tried using the names of the variable that I stored the images in. Also do you know what the value argument is supposed to be?

Comment: Further down In that link that you posted @Suever where it talks about using I1 as the input image and I2 as the reference image, I tried that earlier today getting help from this link (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/166624-calculate-optical-flow-between-two-pictures). After that I tried to plot the result with the plot feature But I kept on getting an error that said it could not do that.

Comment: @enishiyama The "values" are simply the Properties that are listed further down that page. i.e. `o = vision.OpticalFlow('Method', 'Lucas-Kanade')` etc.

Comment: @enishiyama Also you're loading jpegs which are uint8 so you'll want to convert these to double or single precision floating-point numbers `I1 = double(I1)`

Comment: Okay. I will give that a try. On a side note when I was talking about a plotting function is was referring to what's in this link (http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/opticalflow.plot.html). If I just do this: plot(o), where o is the variable that stored the calculation of the optical flow of the two images. Would this technically be correct to plot the optical flow?

Comment: https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/linkexchange/links/3384-robust-local-optical-flow-cpu-gpu-tracking-libary

Answer (score 0):

If you are merely interested in how to visualize optical flow as color and/or arrows, here is a simple script to show you how it can be done in Matlab:

```
% Generate an example flow field
[u,v] = meshgrid(linspace(-1,1)/sqrt(2));
mag = sqrt(u.^2 + v.^2);
an = (atan2(v,u)+pi)/(2*pi);

%display as arrows
subplot(1,2,2);
quiver(u(1:5:end,1:5:end),v(1:5:end,1:5:end));
axis image

%display as color
subplot(1,2,1);
imagesc(hsv2rgb(an,mag,mag));
axis image
```

My [toolbox on optical flow in Matlab](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44400-tutorial-and-toolbox-on-real-time-optical-flow) (which I am now advertising) has at least 3 different ways of visualizing optical flow with a combination of arrows and color coding. To use it with an avi movie file, do as follows:

```
in.movieType = 'example.avi'; % assumes a file 'example.avi' in current folder. 
% in.movieType = 'synthetic';  % generate synthetic video. 
% in.movieType = 'camera';     % assumes a camera available in the system. 

in.method =  @Flow1;       %Locally regularized and vectorized method
% in.method =  @FlowLK;      %Lucas and Kanade 
% in.method =  @FlowHS;      %Horn and Schunk, variational (global regularization)

in.bRecordFlow = 1; %record the optical flow, not only display it

% resolution of flow field [Height Width]:
in.flowRes = [24 24];     %flow resolution <= video resolution

% DO THE CALL TO THE TOOLBOX(initiate the session):
pathToSave = vidProcessing(in);

% view interactively the saved session:
FancyFlowPlayer(pathToSave);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Matlab Computer Vision Toolbox, you can use the built in functions of Lucas-Kanade Optical FLow, Horn-Schunck and Farnebäck.
They both need a grayscale image sequence. They return a Flow object containing the flow in x,y direction aswell as magnitude and angle.
For displaying you can use plot or quiver.